# how to test component parameters in constructor with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a `TestContainer`:

```
class TestContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myValue = 5;
  }
}
```

and I am using Jest with Enzyme for my testing, I would like to test `myValue` is successfully set to 5 when `TestContainer` is rendered. My testing code:

```
describe("TestContainer tests", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TestContainer />);

  it("TestContainer should start", () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    // I dont know how to get the value of myValue.
  });
});
```

Could anyone help please.

Comment: Why *is* myValue set? What's it used for? Why is it not in state?

Comment: I am just testing, would like to know if Jest and Enzyme are capable of testing it if it is written this way.

Comment: Don't test implementation details, what is the usage of this variable? test it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.instance() => ReactComponent](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html#instance--reactcomponent) get the react component instance and make assertion for the value of property `myValue`.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import { Component } from 'react';

export class TestContainer extends Component {
  public myValue = -1;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myValue = 5;
  }
  public render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TestContainer } from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('TestContainer', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestContainer></TestContainer>);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(instance['myValue']).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59281612/index.spec.tsx
  TestContainer
    ✓ should pass (13ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.037s, estimated 11s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59281612